# Python Pandas Iterate over columns and also update columns based on apply conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update dataframe columns based on consecutive columns values.
If columns say col1 and col2 has >0 and <0 values, then same columns should get updated as col2=col1 + col2 and col1=0 and also counter +1 (gives how many fixes has been done throughout the column).

Dataframe look like:

```
id  col0    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5 col6   col7    col8    col9    col10
1   0   5   -5  5   -5  0 0 1   4   3   -3 
2   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 4   -4  0   0 
3   0   0   1   2   3   0 0 0   5   6   0
```

Required Dataframe after applying logic:

```
id  col0    col1    col2    col3    col4    col6    col7    col8    col9    col10   fix
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 1 4   0   0 0 3
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0   0   0 0 1
3   0   0   1   2   3   0   0 0 5   6   0 9 0
```

I tried:

```
def fix_count(row):
    row['fix_cnt'] = 0

    for i in range(0, 10):
        if ((row['col' + str(i)] > 0) & 
            (row['col' + str(i + 1)] < 0)):

            row['col' + str(i + 1)] = row['col' + str(i)] + row['col' + str(i + 1)]
            row['col' + str(i)] = 0

            row['fix_cnt'] += 1

            return (row['col' + str(i)],
                    row['col' + str(i + 1)],
                    row['fix_cnt'])

df.apply(fix_count, axis=1)
```

It failed `IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 11.`

I also looked into `df.iteritems` but I couldn't figure out the way.

DDL to generate DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'col0': [0, 0, 0],
                   'col1': [5, 0, 0],
                   'col2': [-5, 0, 1],
                   'col3': [5, 0, 2],
                   'col4': [-5, 0, 3],
                   'col5' : [0, 0, 0],
                   'col6': [0, 0, 0],
                   'col7': [1, 4, 0],
                   'col8': [4, -4, 5],
                   'col9': [3, 0, 6],
                   'col10': [-3, 0, 0]})
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's no 'col5' in your data and yet you're iterating with range(0,10) which includes 5 in your loop.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, sorry, I missed to add col5. Updated the query for the col5.

Comment: Thanks anky, its works like a charm and been done without loops approach..Just curious..how its done using loop approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach without loops:

```
c = df.gt(0) & df.shift(-1,axis=1).lt(0)

out = (df.mask(c.shift(axis=1).fillna(False),df+df.shift(axis=1))
      .mask(c,0).assign(Fix=c.sum(1)))

print(out)
```

---

```
   id  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col6  col7  col8  col9  col10  Fix
0   1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     4     0      0    3
1   2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0      0    1
2   3     0     0     1     2     3     0     0     5     6      0    0
```

Details:

- `c` checks if current column is > 0 and next column is <0.
- Add current column to next column in the next column to where `c` is
  True.
- Set the current column to 0 if c is True.
- Get sum of c for changes
  done.

Comment: Thanks anky, its works like a charm and  been done without loops approach..Just curious..how its done using loop approach ?

Comment: @Anku 1: i never think of a loop when working with pandas (go for the vectorized approaches when possible) 2: you logic as pointed out by LazyCoder should work but again i wouldnt be too keen in using apply as it is just a wrapper around a for loop, if you have to do with loop you should check first if you can use numpy+numba

Comment: Sure anky! I will look into numpy + numba details.

Comment: @Anku i still am unsure why loops in the first place, but whatever works

Answer (score 1):

Your code logic is fine. Just a small correction while returning the row from your function works as expected:

```
def fix_count(row):
    row['fix_cnt'] = 0

    for i in range(0, 10):
        if ((row['col' + str(i)] > 0) & 
            (row['col' + str(i + 1)] < 0)):

            row['col' + str(i + 1)] = row['col' + str(i)] + row['col' + str(i + 1)]
            row['col' + str(i)] = 0

            row['fix_cnt'] += 1

    return (row)

df.apply(fix_count, axis=1)
```

Try this and let me know if this works!

Comment: Yeah! So I was just missing last part (return row).